# boolean part of the code does not work in java

Tags: java, string, boolean

Hi I have to program this :

```
public class Book {

    String title;
    boolean borrowed;

    // Creates a new Book
    public Book(String bookTitle) {
        // Implement this method
    }

    // Marks the book as rented
    public void borrowed() {
        // Implement this method
    }

    // Marks the book as not rented
    public void returned() {
        // Implement this method
    }

    // Returns true if the book is rented, false otherwise
    public boolean isBorrowed() {
        // Implement this method
    }

    // Returns the title of the book
    public String getTitle() {
        // Implement this method
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        // Small test of the Book class
        Book example = new Book("The Da Vinci Code");
        System.out.println("Title (should be The Da Vinci Code): " + example.getTitle());
        System.out.println("Borrowed? (should be false): " + example.isBorrowed());
        example.rented();
        System.out.println("Borrowed? (should be true): " + example.isBorrowed());
        example.returned();
        System.out.println("Borrowed? (should be false): " + example.isBorrowed());
    }
}
```

the output should be like this :

```
Title (should be The Da Vinci Code): The Da Vinci Code
Rented? (should be false): false
Rented? (should be true): true
Rented? (should be false): false
```

I did like this :

```
public class Book {
String title;
boolean borrowed;
// Creates a new Book
public Book(String bookTitle) {
// Implement this method
    String book=new String();
}
// Marks the book as rented
public void borrowed() {
// Implement this method
    borrowed=true;
}
// Marks the book as not rented
public void returned() {
// Implement this method
    borrowed=false;
}
// Returns true if the book is rented, false otherwise
public boolean isBorrowed() {
// Implement this method

    if (book=borrowed()){
        return true;
    }else if(book==returned()){
        return false;

    }
}

// Returns the title of the book
public String getTitle() {
// Implement this method
    return "The Da Vinci Code";

} 
public static void main(String[] arguments) {
// Small test of the Book class
Book example = new Book("The Da Vinci Code");
System.out.println("Title (should be The Da Vinci Code): " + example.getTitle());
System.out.println("Borrowed? (should be false): " + example.isBorrowed());
System.out.println("Borrowed? (should be true): " + example.isBorrowed());
System.out.println("Borrowed? (should be false): " + example.isBorrowed());
}
}
```

I think my code is generally good but eclipse says : book cannot be resolved to a variable .. in the following part :

```
public boolean isBorrowed() {
// Implement this method

    if (book=borrowed()){
        return true;
    }else if(book==returned()){
        return false;

    }
}
```

How can I correct the problem in the previous part of the code ?
and did I do correct for the rest of the code ?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's zoom in on this piece of code:

```
if (book=borrowed()) {
        return true;
} else if(book==returned()) {
        return false;
}
```

First thing to note is when checking for equality you use `==`, the `=` operator is for assignments. For example, `borrowed == true` checks if `borrowed` is true, and `borrowed = true` assigns `borrowed` to true.

Second thing to note is that book isn't even a variable available in `isBorrowed` because you didn't save it as an instance variable like you did for `borrowed` and `title`.

Third thing to note is your checks `book == borrowed()` and `book == returned()` don't make sense. `borrowed()` and `returned()` are `void` methods so they don't return anything, and book is a string. What you really want to check is if the variable `borrowed` is true or false:

```
if (borrowed == true) {
    return true;
} else if (borrowed == false) {
    return false;
}
```

which can be simplified to just this:

```
return borrowed;
```

You also need to change your `main` method to call the appropriate methods between the print statements:

```
System.out.println("Title (should be The Da Vinci Code): " + example.getTitle());
System.out.println("Borrowed? (should be false): " + example.isBorrowed());
example.borrowed();
System.out.println("Borrowed? (should be true): " + example.isBorrowed());
example.returned();
System.out.println("Borrowed? (should be false): " + example.isBorrowed());
```

Comment: thank you brother .. do know how to get output like this : Rented? (should be false): false
Rented? (should be true): true
Rented? (should be false): false

Comment: @ramialsaiad you aren't calling your methods in `main`. I edited my answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define a `book` variable in `isBorrowed()`, so it's undefined and you should have received a compiler error about that.

Even if you had a `book` variable, the `isBorrowed()` method is way too complicated.  Just return `borrowed`.

You'll also want to call `borrowed()` and `returned()`, before and after calling the second `isBorrowed()`, respectively, for a proper test.

Additionally, set the `title` variable in the constructor.

```
this.title = bookTitle;
```

And return `title` in `getTitle()`, instead of hard-coding it.

Comment: Hi I did what you said .. there is no compiler error but I do not understand what you mean by : "You'll also want to call borrowed() and returned(), before and after calling the second isBorrowed(), respectively, for a proper test." .. did I do wrong in borrowed() and returned() ??

Comment: No, the `borrowed()` and `returned()` methods look good.  In your code under "I did like this", you didn't call `borrowed()` or `returned()` in `main`.

Comment: thank you .. when I run the code I get : Title (should be The Da Vinci Code): The Da Vinci Code
Borrowed? (should be false): false
Borrowed? (should be true): false
Borrowed? (should be false): false ....... it should be false then true then false

Comment: Like I said, you didn't call `borrowed()` or `returned()`.